# Coloring text in scrlayer-notecolumn (XeLaTeX)?

Tags: xetex, koma-script, tcolorbox, scrlayer-notecolumn

I am trying to use [KOMA-script notecolumns](https://komascript.de/%7Emkohm/scrguien.pdf#chapter.19) with XeLaTeX. I want to make the notes nicer by using the package [tcolorbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=en). In the KOMA-script manual it is mentioned that `\color{}` commands don't work with XeLaTeX (+ scrlayer-notecolumn) :

> Because the package was designed only as a proof of concept and because XETEX does not support multiple colour stacks, XETEX colour switching is restricted to the attributes of the font element *notecolumn.note column name*, a limitation which eliminates the time and effort required to implement custom colour management.

The following code will compile:

```
%! TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass[oneside, titlepage = false, fontsize = 12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}

\usepackage{fontspec,geometry}

\setmainfont{cmun}[
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*rm,
    ItalicFont=*ti,
    BoldFont=*bx,
    BoldItalicFont=*bi,
]

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem[]{memoanmich}{Memo an mich selbst}{colback=black!15,colframe=black!80,fonttitle=\bfseries,left=0mm,right=0mm}{memoanmich}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{left=1.8cm, right=5.6cm, top = 2cm, bottom = 3cm, marginpar=5cm, footskip = 1cm}

\makenote*{\begin{small}\begin{memoanmich*}{}{}Some maths: $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^2$ \end{memoanmich*}\end{small}}

test

\end{document}
```

But the compiler will complain and throw the following warning 4 times:

> Package scrlayer-notecolumn Warning: unsupported change of colour! It seems you are using a TeX engine, that does not support switching the colour stack like pdfTeX or luaTeX do. Because of this, usage of \color, \textcolor etc. inside a note column is not supported.

The result is mostly ok:

[image]

except for the title "Memo an mich selbst" which should have a much lighter color but `tcolorbox` failed to change it (because I use `XeLaTeX`). I found a workaround: the `fontspec` command `\addfontfeature{Color=...}`.

So instead of:

```
\makenote*{\begin{small}\begin{memoanmich*}{}{}%
Some maths: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^2$%
\end{memoanmich*}\end{small}}
```

I use:

```
\makenote*{\addfontfeature{Color=FFFFFE}\begin{small}\begin{memoanmich*}{}{}%
\addfontfeature{Color=black}Some maths: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^2$%
\end{memoanmich*}\end{small}}
```

Questions:

1. The `fontspec` command `\addfontfeature{Color=...}` solves my problem but I still get the warning mentioned above because of `tcolorbox`. Is there some way to do this properly i.e. get rid of the warning?
2. Why doesn't `\addfontfeature{Color=...}` work when I use "white" or "FFFFFF" as an argument?
3. `\addfontfeature{Color=...}` influences just regular text. Is there some way to color the math text?
4. Will `XeLaTeX` ever support multiple color stacks (whatever that is)?

Comment: The answer to the last question is probably no but aside from trying to supress warnings, why do you need XeLaTeX instead of LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @TeXnician I don't know if I need XeLaTeX. I looked for comparisons of all TeX engines and concluded that XeTeX is the way to go for me (best UTF-8 support) but those comparisons are "old" (several years) so maybe in 2020, the difference is negligible and I should switch to LuaTeX.

Comment: LuaLaTeX in 2020 uses the same font shaping as XeLaTeX. And Unicode coverage is equally good, plus it is pdf-based and has Lua available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Imho it doesn't make much sense to deactivate colors completely only because they can fail at page breaks. You can reactivate the colors as in the following example.

```
\documentclass[oneside, titlepage = false, fontsize = 12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}



\usepackage{fontspec,geometry}

\setmainfont{cmun}[
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*rm,
    ItalicFont=*ti,
    BoldFont=*bx,
    BoldItalicFont=*bi,
]

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

 
\newtcbtheorem[]{memoanmich}{Memo an mich selbst}{colback=black!15,colframe=black!80,fonttitle=\bfseries,left=0mm,right=0mm}{memoanmich}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\slnc@switchcolorstack{\set@color}{\@dummy@set@color}{}{\fail}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}


\newgeometry{left=1.8cm, right=5.6cm, top = 2cm, bottom = 3cm, marginpar=5cm, footskip = 1cm}

\makenote*{\begin{small}\begin{memoanmich*}{}{}Some maths: $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^2$ \end{memoanmich*}\end{small}}

test

\end{document}
```

2. That FFFFFF doesn't work is a bug which has been resolved in the sources but the fix will be probably  available only with texlive 2021 (but perhaps xdvipdfmx is updated earlier).
3. color stacks allow to keep track for color over page breaks. If at the end of a page "red" is active, one has to reinsert the code for "red" at the begin of the next page in a pdf. If you have more than one textflow that breaks over pages, e.g. the main text, a splitted footnote, and like here a side column, you need a color stack for every one to track each color state. Currently there is only one stack in xelatex, so only the main text can track the color, but there is an open feature request and some hope to get more.